# Exception JNI (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have made a little program in java that accepts a string as a user input. Now i have made a dll writing its code in Visual C++. when i run my program from netbeans it displays this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Prompt.getLine(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at Prompt.getLine(Native Method)
        at Prompt.main(Prompt.java:19)
```

What problem is this. Need Help. Thanks

This is java code

```
public class Prompt {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private native String getLine(String prompt);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Prompt p = new Prompt();
        String input = p.getLine("Type a line:");
        System.out.println("User Typed:" + input);
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Prompt");
        //System.load("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin/Prompt.dll");
    }
}
```

and this is C++ Code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include "jni_md.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Prompt_getLine(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring prompt)
{
    char buf[128];
    const char *str;
    str = env->GetStringUTFChars(prompt,0);
    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL; /* OutOfMemoryError already thrown */
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(prompt, str);
    /* We assume here that the user does not type more than
    * 127 characters */
    scanf("%s", buf);
    return env->NewStringUTF(buf);
}
```

Comment: have you loaded dll? can you post your code.

Comment: yeah i have loaded it, sure i will post it

Comment: ` System.loadLibrary("Prompt");`  isn't it should be path to DLL the same as commented one ?

Comment: i have placed the Prompt.dll in java library path so i can load it also in this way

Comment: Either i have also tried by giving the path as well but same exception

Comment: Try putting somewhere lets say `c:\dlls` and try  `System.loadLibrary("c://dlls//Prompt.dll");` It should work ,Note these double forward slash

Comment: still the same exception

Comment: There must be something wrong with your dll build I guess.

Comment: i am also guessing this out, may be something getting wrong in my dll.

Comment: is there any problem with the code of c++?

Comment: I would suggest compare your work with http://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/beginning-jni-win.html. and makeout where the problem is

Comment: ok let me try with this one :)

Comment: @org.life.java....i got the problem and it was my mistake, i was not including the header file of java which is JNI style header file which is Prompt.h in c++, "#include "jni_md.h" this will be eliminated and included "Prompt.h" now it is working fine.

Comment: thnx for your time :), i need to ask one more thing,how can i get the very good help related to JNI i mean any tutorial or book. Its been like a 6-7 years that i have touched c++, but still working on java.

Comment: you can add answer to this question and accept it to make this question answered.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html  this is standard place i feel,

Comment: Does anyone have an up-to-date link to that Sun (now Oracle) online training?  Sadly, that link is now broken :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@org.life.java....i got the problem and it was my mistake, i was not including the header file of java which is JNI style header file which is `Prompt.h` in c++, "`#include "jni_md.h`" this will be eliminated and included `"Prompt.h"` now it is working fine.